# How to check current user in meta value array in WP_Query meta_query

Tags: query, meta-query

I am having trouble to query cpt for the current user if s/he is in the meta value array.

## query args

```
$args = [
    'post_type'      => $cp::get_module_cpt(),
    'posts_per_page' => - 1,
    'meta_query'     => [
        'relation' => 'AND',
        [
            'key'     => 'premium_module',
            'value'   => 0,
            'compare' => '=',
        ],
        [
            'key'     => 'permit_users',
            'value'   => get_current_user_id(),
            'compare' => 'IN',
        ],
    ],
];
```

## meta key

`permit_users`

## meta value

#### if has value

```
Array
(
    [0] => 29
    [1] => 28
    ...
)
```

#### if has no value

return false or empty array. Depends if ever set the field before.

#### additionally,

I have tried setting compare to `=` equal but that also didn't work. Probably since the value is in array.

### Result Looking

The query should return all posts that have current user id in the `permit_users` key.

> **Important:**
>   The `permit_users` is an optional, so if the field has not value (false) or empty array, the query should ignore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't easily query inside arrays inside a meta value. This is because there's no such thing as an array value in MySQL. Instead the value is stored as a [serialized](https://www.w3resource.com/php/function-reference/serialize.php) string.

So an array like this:

```
array(
    0 => 29,
    1 => 28,
);
```

Is stored in the database as this string:

```
a:2:{i:0;i:29;i:1;i:28;}
```

So the only way to find values inside it is to do a `LIKE` on the string. But the problem is that if you want to check if the value `28` is in the array, you'd need to query `LIKE '%:28;%'`, but apart from being much slower, could give you incorrect results if `28` is an index in the array.

So instead of storing an array, use `add_post_meta()` to add multiple rows for the same meta key. For example, if you use:

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'permit_users', [ 29, 28 ] );
```

You will get:

```
+--------------+--------------------------+
|   meta_key   |        meta_value        |
+--------------+--------------------------+
| permit_users | a:2:{i:0;i:29;i:1;i:28;} |
+--------------+--------------------------+
```

But if you use:

```
add_post_meta( $post_id, 'permit_user', 28 );
add_post_meta( $post_id, 'permit_user', 29 );
```

You will get:

```
+-------------+------------+
|  meta_key   | meta_value |
+-------------+------------+
| permit_user |         28 |
| permit_user |         29 |
+-------------+------------+
```

And your `WP_Query` using `IN` will work the way you expect:

```
[
    'key'     => 'permit_user',
    'value'   => get_current_user_id(),
    'compare' => 'IN',
],
```

Comment: Great. thanks a lot. Solved.